# Newly created user can't be validated

Tags: c#, directoryservices, account-management

```
  
  using(PrincipalContext cntx = new PrincipalContext(
        ContextType.Domain, "blah.corp.net:389", "OU=customers,OU=web,CN=blah,CN=corp,CN=net", 
        ContextOptions.Negotiate, "Domin\Admin", "{Password}")){
        string password = "PPaass00!!";
        UserPrincipal p = new UserPrincipal(cntx);
        p.SamAccountName = "GuestUser";
        p.PasswordNeverExpires = true;
        p.Enabled = true;
        p.SetPassword(password);
        p.Save();
        bool b = cntx.ValidateCredentials("GuestUser", password); //where b always false
    }
```

I don't understand why b is always false. Can anyone help?

Comment: 1 out of 10 (accepted answers). Why? Were your previous questions poor or you didn't get satisfying answers or you simply don't know [how does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Comment: All you had to do was tag it [c#] and you'll instantly get C# syntax highlighting... the system is smarter than you think.

Comment: learning the advanced format :-)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the answer to your question, have you tried this method instead?

```
PrincipalContext cntx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
    "blah.corp.net:389", 
    "OU=customers,OU=web,CN=blah,CN=corp,CN=net",ContextOptions.Negotiate, 
    "Domin\GuestUser", password)
```

Put a try/catch around it and see if it throws an exception when you connect or not.

Comment: no exception thrown. after research, it seem user account somehow is not enabled, that's why the verify authentication always failed.

Comment: So enabling the user during or after creation, but before authentication, resolved your issue?